Is my proof of showing $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$ is linearly independent correct here?

Prove that if $\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ is linearly independent and $v_{3}$ is not in the $span(v_{1},v_{2})$, then $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$ is linearly independent

Ok so to prove above I took the contrapositive instead which is (correct me if I'm wrong)
If $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$ is linearly dependent, then $\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ is linearly dependent or $v_3$ is in the $span(v_1,v_2)$. I proceed as follows:
Because $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$ is linearly dependent, we can write it as
$$c_{1}v_{1}+c_{2}v_{2}+c_{3}v_{3}=0$$ where not all the $c$'s are zero.
Then we can write it as
$$v_{3}=\left(-\frac{c_{1}}{c_{3}}\right)v_{1}+\left(-\frac{c_{2}}{c_{3}}\right)v_{2}$$
Which shows that $v_{3}$ is in the $span(v_{1},v_{2})$. Did I do the proof correctly, and if so is there a way to prove the statement the normal way without taking the contrapositive?

Well...to be complete you need to argue that $c_3\neq 0$.   Note that you never used the assumption that $v_1, v_2$ were independent.

Ah so I should say that $c_{3}$ is not $0$ (from the linear independency condition)?

I would explain why that follows from independence.

What happens if $c_3 = 0$ ?

I meant to say $c_{3} \neq 0$ because of linear dependency, woops...

We can prove this directly.
$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=0\implies c_1v_1+c_2v_2=-c_3v_3$$
Since $v_3$ is not in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$, $c_3$ must be zero, otherwise we can divide by $c_3$ and show that $c_3$ is in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$.
This gives $$c_1v_1+c_2v_2=0\implies c_1=c_2=0$$ because $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent.
Therefore, $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ and the three vectors are linearly independent.

@YvesDaoust It is fundamentally different. I did not assume the vectors were dependent. This is a direct proof. We start from $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=0$ and show that all three constants must be zero.

@YvesDaoust The question was to write a direct proof. That is what this is. The original proof used the contrapositive.
